Test a Perplexity API key on python
I don't find an efficient way to check if an api key of perplexity is valid, either on python or anything.
Indeed, for openai I do :
def check_openai_api_key(api_key):
    openai.api_key = api_key
    try:
        openai.Model.list()
    except openai.error.AuthenticationError as e:
        return False
    else:
        return True

But perplexity does not seem to have a model index. Does anyone know how I could do ?
Currently I do a simple completion request with the API like so :
def check_perplexity_api_key(api_key):
    url = "https://api.perplexity.ai/chat/completions"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    data = {
        "model": "llama-3.1-sonar-small-128k-online",
        "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "SOME PROMPT TO ASK AN EASY AND QUICK THING"}]
    }
    
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
        print(response.content)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False

but it's ineficient, takes time and consumes tokens.
What would you suggest ?
Thanks in advance !
